# How to change an int value by strings combination

Tags: python

I need to change an int value by strings combination

```
x = 'person'
y = '400'

person400 = 1000

eval(x + y) = 3000 #i want to change person400 value by strings combination 


print(person400) # print 3000
```

Comment: You get help here: [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: Why would you want to do that? This seems like an XY problem to me. What is your goal.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`eval` only evaluates the value of an expression. So if you want to execute a line of code you need to use `exec`.

Also the whole assignment needs to be inside exec, so that everything gets run as one line of code.
`exec(x + y + '= 3000')`.
Which in your example will run as `exec('person400 = 3000')`.

However this is a really bad way of setting variables so make sure you think it makes sense.

Comment: Did you test it?

Comment: @blhsing My mistake. Corrected the ans